# Using Python script execute SQL query stored in a notepad file

Tags: python, sql

The SQL query is stored in a notepad file. Need to run this using Python scripts

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
with open('C:\Python_Script_Test\SQL_Query.txt','r') as inserts:
   query = inserts.read()
cursor.execute(query)
```

Expected is that the query should execute.

Actual getting below error:

> with open('C:\Python_Script_Test\SQL_Query.txt','r') as inserts:
> "
> syntax error: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec cant decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

error is pointing at the comma inserted in the above line just before mode.
tried replacing single quotes with double but no luck
also, my query is multi line.

Please help

Comment: Does this answers your question ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/how-should-i-write-a-windows-path-in-a-python-string-literal

Comment: You have backslashes in your path, not sure that this is your problem, but try to use either a raw string literal `r"C:\Python_Script_Test\......"` or escaping the backslash like `"C:\\Python_Script_Test\\......"`

Comment: You answer has not enough information. What encoding the file has?

Comment: escaping the backlash is the correct way.....was able to resolve then. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

As you have a utf8 encoding you need to tell it to the app

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
with open('C:\\Python_Script_Test\\SQL_Query.txt','r', encoding="utf-8") as inserts:
   query = inserts.read()
cursor.execute(query)
```

of course there could be other UTf encioding envolved

Comment: This is working. adding the encoding parameter is solving the issue very nicely.  Many Thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

```py
cursor = connection.cursor()
with open('C:\\Python_Script_Test\\SQL_Query.txt','r', encoding="utf-8") as inserts:
   query = inserts.read()
cursor.execute(query)
```

this is solving the issue.
Addition of encoding parameter and escaping the backslash "\" resolved this issue.

Thanks for the help !!